# Using a company iPad privately

Tags: ipad, apple-id

My boss has given each employee an iPad 2 with the express permission to use it privately as well as professionaly (take it home, install apps, ...).

All iPads are used with the same company-wide Apple ID, so that all devices are automatically synchronised. However, I also have a private Apple ID and I'm wondering how I could get content I purchased with my private ID on my new iPad. While we are allowed to buy non-free apps with the company's apple ID if we pay for them with iTunes store cards, I would rather buy content with my own Apple ID so that I can keep it.

- Is it possible to abandon the principle that all company iPads are used with the same ID and still get automatical synchronisation?
- Is it possible to use content purchased with my Apple ID while logged in with another ID?
- Are there any other things which are good to know in my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad will allow you to run any app installed on it, no matter what Apple ID it is associated with. You will need to switch to your account when you first download the app, and then switch back. The app will continue to run normally, and if there are any updates you can download them without switching accounts (the App Store will ask for your account's password). I am not sure which account will be used if you try to make an in-app purchase, though, so be careful.